# Simple error check in html form with php?

Tags: php

Newb here, sorry in advance. I want to check for errors in a simple html form. I want the form to email me the customers information. I have my contact.php and errorcheck.php uploaded to my hosting provider. i actually made a working script contactform.php. (working) So I have a clue that my host can process the php code, but my errorcheck.php script is not working. Can anyone check my errorcheck.php script and see what may be causing the problem. all I want errorcheck.php to do so far, is display the error in the web address bar, just so I know that its working. Thanks in advance for helping a newb. I hope I explained my self and code well enough.

contactform.php (working script will connect and send me an email of form information)
errorcheck.php (will not connect or check the form for errors, I want to display the error in web address bar)
contact.php (this is the html form)

errorcheck.php code below

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $first = $_POST['name'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    //check if inputs are empty
    if (empty($first) || empty($mail) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) {
        header("Location:contact.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first)) {
            header("Location:contact.php?signup=char");
            exit();
        } else {
            //check if email is valid
            if (!fiter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                header("Location:contact.php?signup=invalid-email");
                exit();
            } else {
                header("Location:contact.php?signup=signup=success");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(html code will connect to contactform.php but not errorcheck.php)

contact.php form code is below

```
        <form class="contact-form" action="contactform.php" method="post">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name..">
            <label for="mail">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Your E-Mail..">
            <label for="subject">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Phone Number..">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message.."></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></input>
        </form>
```

contactform.php code is below

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mailTo = "sales@screenrunners.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received and e-mail from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;


    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: contact.php?mailsend");

}

?>
```

Comment: I can see at least 1 error(typo). You have written `fiter_var` instead of `filter_var`

Comment: You now do action="contactform.php". What happens when you do put action="errorcheck.php" ? Can't see anything obvious other that the typo EhsanT mentioned.

Comment: Both comments worked !!!!!!  Thank you so much EshanT and clash for you quick replies. Great help from both of you. I can't believe the code actually works. I guess while I'm coding I always feel like there is no way this is going to work, but then somehow after hours of researching and digging around online, when you finally get things to work, it feels really good. Thanks so much for helping me guys. I would like to make this solved and edit the code in case anyone would ever want to use this. I doubt they would but hey you never know it may help somebody out there. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it was essentially a typo. @BobbyDoughnuts that's not to take away your excitement for this working now, but because SO is essentially a reference website and this is a specific error, it's unlikely to be a general solution for future readers.

Comment: No problem. I still think it may be able to help people create a simple php contact form, but if you have to delete it your the boss. Thanks.